# Can Google location be mistaken -- association with contacts

Tags: applications

My girlfriend was located at a house in a town that she works in. I asked whose house and she replied she'd never been there. I drove by on my own after dropping her off and recognizedo the car in the driveway as belonging to a coworker of hers. So could this be because they phone each other and their phones somehow connected to each other pinpointing her there while never physically there. A random house is a e asy  you shrug, but to be her coworkers home out of 500 homes seems against good odds.

Comment: Location services are not always accurate. Instead they are approximate. It may vary according to different reasons though.

Answer (score 0):

Location services are usually accurate within a certain range. For example, google tells me my location is accurate within 30m. Obviously, your mileage may vary.

You can find detailed information about *your* location history with timestamps over [here](https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0).